# How to build an editable view of two entities linked together?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I started using drupal recently and i am stuck building an editableview.

In my view i have a table of users with a field of a content type **"survey"** associated to theim throught an entity reference field that i added to the user account's fields.
i set up a view of user with a relationship to my entity reference field.

I want to edit the field **"active"** wich is a field of content type **"survey"**

At the moment i can edit the field but it will set the value for every content.
[image]

i wish to edit the value of desired content not for all the content of this content type.Is their a way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a relation and editing a field of the relationed content "Survey", if a "User" is relationed to the same Survey content, will change on all of them.

If it is a different node "Survey" for each "User", it should't change all of them. I just did a test with your conditions and everything is going great. Could you give more information like configuration, multivalued, etc. of  those fields?